# Reset forms on angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

im trying to get some values in forms using the submit event. But i can´t reset those forms later. Im trying to use an id called "myForm" and an onclick function

```
                        <form (Submit)="addMarker()" id="myForm">
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lat" name="lat" class="form-control" placeholder="Latitud">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lng" name="lng" class="form-control" placeholder="Longitud">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()">Agregar Marcador</button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Script:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your HTML:

```
<form (submit)="addMarker(myForm)" id="myForm" #myForm="ngForm"> // <-- Notice the "#"
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lat" name="lat" class="form-control" placeholder="Latitud">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lng" name="lng" class="form-control" placeholder="Longitud">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar Marcador</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In your ts:

Import NgForm first by adding:

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
```

Function to reset the form:

```
addMarker(form: NgForm) {
    //do something and then reset the form
    form.resetForm();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 2 Final, we now have a new API that cleanly resets the form:

```
@Component({...})
class App {

    form: FormGroup;
     ...
    reset() {
       this.form.reset();
   }
}
```

This API not only resets the form values, but also sets the form field states back to `ng-pristine` and `ng-untouched`.